# Create a black window with as little memory as possible

Tags: code-challenge

Today I installed [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net) and ran the test application, which creates a basic colored window. I was surprised to see that the process was using 32.2 MiB of memory, and I thought it could be improved.

[image]

Your challenge is to write a program that creates a 640 by 480 window displaying only black pixels. Whatever program uses the least physical memory to do so wins. You may use any operating system released after the year 2000.

Comment: I suppose we cannot shut down the computer?

Comment: [tag:restricted-memory] is not the right tag for this. [I proposed a challenge type for memory golf a while back](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8513/45941), but the community hasn't yet come up with a good, fair way to measure memory. For the time being, I'm going to replace the tag with [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: If memory cannot be reliably measured, this could make a nice code-golf challenge

Comment: This is why this site sucks. I ask a clear question, nobody complains about it or asks for clarification, yet it is put on hold.

Comment: @EMBLEM: The problem is the scoring criterion. How to you measure memory? _When_ do you measure memory? Peak usage? Usage after a while of doing nothing and stabilising? I've got six different memory measurements alone on a process on Windows. Which one is the one to report here?

Comment: @Joey Great, I'm glad you told me that! Now I can go back and improve the question. If only the five close voters had done the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 96KiB

Never seen `restricted-memory` but i guess code length doesn't matter here. RAM usage was taken from gnome-system-monitor (i hope it's accurate).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
 
int main ()
{
  xcb_connection_t    *c;
  xcb_screen_t        *screen;
  xcb_drawable_t       win;
  xcb_generic_event_t *e;
  uint32_t             values[2];
 
  char string[] = " ";
 
  c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);
  screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;
  win = screen->root;
 
  win = xcb_generate_id(c);
  values[0] = screen->black_pixel;
  values[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS;
  xcb_create_window (c,XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,win,screen->root,
  0, 0,640,480,10,XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,screen->root_visual,XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, values);
 
  xcb_map_window (c, win); 
  xcb_flush (c);
 
  while ((e = xcb_wait_for_event (c))) {
    switch (e->response_type & ~0x80) {
    case XCB_EXPOSE:
      xcb_flush (c);
      break;
    }
    free (e);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code works on pretty much every linux with a running xserver. To compile add `-lxcb` for the xcb libs.

Comment: This is why Linux > Windows, the Windows equivalent using WinAPI + GDI uses 1.4MB

Comment: According to `valgrind`, the memory usage always peaks at 12,849,152 bytes when compiled using GCC 5.4.0 (with only your `-lxcb`; `-Os` doesn't do anything) on my system during the `xcb_connect` call (and then returns to around 100kiB while the window is being displayed.)